# A lot of Jquery and check/radio/select styled elements — Flash of unstyled content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with a lot of jQuery elements (large jquery files) and the problem with this is that the styled elements that replace standard HTML elements (checkboxes, radiobuttons and selectboxes/dropdown) shows the standard appearance for some millisecond at page load.

Is there any way to make the exchanged for those elements to show faster?

The elements scripts use ready() and is placed in head. The optimal solution would be if the changed elements load direcly insteed of the standard elements (but I guess that dont work).

The plugin I use to style the elements is:

[jqtransform](http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/)

[Selectyze](https://github.com/alpixel/Selectyze)

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> shows the standard appearance for some millisecond at page load

You can prevent that by hiding your whole page (via `display:none`) until the elements are styled by your plugins:

```
<head>
    …
    <style …>
    <script src="plugins…" …>
    <script>
    (function() {
        var hide = $('<style type="text/css">body { display: none; }</style>');
        $("head").append(hide);

        $(document).ready(function(){
             …
             // apply your plugins
             …
             hide.remove();
        });
    })();
</head>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could have your standard elements with `display: none` as style at page load and only `show()` them using JQuery after they have been styled.

**Sidenote:** jqTransform is [no longer supported](https://github.com/jcamenisch/jqTransform) as a plugin.

Comment: Hey. What do you mean by the jqTranform is no longer supported? Just that the develeper have shut down the project? Or is it not supported in jquery in some way?

Comment: No longer supported by the developer, which means you may have problems with later versions of JQuery.